# Convert pandas series into integers

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe like this:

```
'John', 0.25
'Mary', 0.2
'Adam', 0.1
'Andrew', 0.6
```

I would like to generate a unique integer for every category in a certain series. For example, in the case above, the output could be something like this

```
0, 0.25
1, 0.2
2, 0.1
3, 0.6
```

possibly with pandas or standard libraries only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) like:

```
print df
          a     b
0    'John'  0.25
1    'Mary'  0.20
2    'Mary'  0.20
3    'Adam'  0.10
4    'Adam'  0.10
5    'Adam'  0.10
6  'Andrew'  0.60

print pd.factorize(df.a)
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]), 
 Index([u''John'', u''Mary'', u''Adam'', u''Andrew''], dtype='object'))

df['a'] = pd.factorize(df.a)[0]
print df

   a     b
0  0  0.25
1  1  0.20
2  1  0.20
3  2  0.10
4  2  0.10
5  2  0.10
6  3  0.60
```

Comment: would it be possible to generalize to the case where I don't know how many unique values do I have?

Comment: I try add new rows, please check, if I understand correctly your question.